# Are User in WebApiController and HttpContext.Current.User different?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication, iprincipal

After referring [this post](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/), I wrote an attribute for Basic Http Authentication to be used in the web api. In the attribute class, if the credentials provided match, then I am setting the HttpContext.Current.User as

```
 HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new ApiIdentity(apiUser), new string[] {});

base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
```

However, when I access User inside my api controller, it does not have the apiUser properties.

Why is this and what is the correct way to set an Identity and then access it in api controller?

Answer (score 2):

Nope - you have to set both unfortunately.

Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.User

Answer (score 1):

In your ASP.NET Web API application, you shouldn't rely on current `HttpContext`. As for the answer to your question, setting the principal to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is what you would want:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new ApiIdentity(apiUser), new string[] {});
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you rely on current HttpContext?

Comment: @user210757 See https://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/25/important-setting-the-client-principal-in-asp-net-web-api/